# RS485 half duplex mode in full duplex IC

Tags: rs485

[Datasheet link](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM2582E_2587E.pdf)
I am unsing full duplex RS485 feature IC.

Please confirm below

To use this IC in half duplex mode I need to short Pin B to pin z and Pin A to Pin Y.
Since thease pins are internally not shorted ( beacuse it is full duplex feature IC).
[image]

Comment: Yeah just connect them. Basically treat this IC as if it was 2 separate MAX485 transceivers.

Comment: Perhaps looking at datasheet sometimes, can answer lot of questions.

Comment: Don't forget that you can combine nRE and DE to one net in half duplex.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct -- Y to A and Z to B is what you need to do for a half duplex app -- you can also connect DE to /RE on the other side.